# Django modelformset_factory invalid, return request.POST data to forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to return the data that has been entered back in place in the form using django modelformset_factory

*view*

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

ArticleFormSet = modelformset_factory(Article, extra=2)
formset = ArticleFormSet(queryset=Article.objects.none())

if request.POST:
    formset = ArticleFormSet(request.POST)

    if formset.is_valid():
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        formset = ArticleFormSet(queryset=instances)
    else:
        ## ?? RETURN formset with request.POST data in form ??
        pass
```

*template*

```
<form method="POST" id="articleForm" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
  {% for form in forms %}
    {{form.as_p}}
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Using Django 1.4 I'm getting:

```
Validation Error: No exception supplied
```

Have tried a range for variations on `initial=request.POST`, but no joy.

Any advice is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked to see if the "management form" details were not being automatically passed, turns out they weren't (per here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform).

Cobbling this "Management Form data" on to `request.POST` seems to have resolved the otherwise mysterious `validation` error. I wonder if this a genuine 1.4 bug?

```
if request.POST:
    forms_mgmt = {'form-TOTAL_FORMS': u'2', 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': u'0', 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': u''}
    data_dict = dict(request.POST.items() + forms_mgmt.items())

    formset = ArticleFormSet(data_dict)

    if formset.is_valid():
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        formset = ArticleFormSet(queryset=instances)
```

Thanks to @Daniel Roseman for helping me not go down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. Your formset is already populated with the POST data. Just pass that to the template. The usual way to do this is not to have an else clause, but just fall through to the same render call that displayed the forms in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this! This is what I thought. There must be some other bug. as it's still returning `validation error` based on the line `formset = ArticleFormSet(request.POST)`, I suspect there is a problem with the model, though tried a simplified model and had the same problem ... I will keep searching, thank you.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback, please? Hard to debug with just that one line.

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Williams answer, reading through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform you can find that the management form data that can be rendered into the template with `{{ my_formset.management_form }}`:

```html
<form method="POST" id="articleForm" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for form in forms %}
        {{form.as_p}}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ my_formset.management_form }}
</form>
```

Then, once the form has been posted you can use:

```py
formset = ArticleFormSet(request.POST)
```